# se puede sumar las filas o columnas de una tabla?

Tags: javascript

quiero sumar las columnas de una tabla

```html
<table id="ejemplo" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr class="encabezado">
            <th>Campo 1</th>
            <th>Campo 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

estos datos vienen de un arreglo, debo sumar en el arreglo o puedo sumar las columnas de la tabla directamente.

Comment: @RubenHernandez no es con php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mira algo como esto

```js
var total=0;
$("#ejemplo tbody tr").each(function(){
 total+=parseFloat($(this).find("td").eq(0).text());
});
$("#total").text(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="ejemplo" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="encabezado">
      <th>Campo 1</th>
      <th>Campo 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th id="total">Total</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Saludos :)

Comment: puedes crear un sniper, crealo por favor

Comment: Genial no había creado ninguno gracias por apoyarme :)

Comment: y sin class se puede?

Comment: Listo modificado :)